# Codeigniter - not logging in

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, model, controller

I'm trying to learn MVC and codeigniter and trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to login with a very simple form that contains email and password. 
In the controller I first load the view that contains a form. When everything is filled in and clicked in the 'loginSubmit' button, it should go to 'login()' in my controller.

In my methode 'login()' I load the model, where I call the 'validate()' methode. When it returns something I return a true to my controller to start a session and redirect me to profiles page.

The problem now is, whatever I'm giving in to login in, it always refreshes the login controller with the login methode

So I browse to

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/login/
```

when pressing submit is brings me to

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/login/login/
```

Why isn't it doing any check, what is happening?

**login_view**

```
<?php
    $loginEmail = array('placeholder' => "Email", 'name' => "loginEmail");
    $loginPassword = array('placeholder' => "Wachtwoord", 'name' => "loginPassword");
    $loginSubmit = array('name' => "loginSubmit", 'class' => "btn", 'value' => "Inloggen");
    $loginForgot = array('name' => "loginForgot", 'class' => "link", 'value' => "Wachtwoord vergeten?");

    echo form_open('login/login', array('class' => 'grid-100 formc'));
    echo form_input($loginEmail);
    echo form_password($loginPassword);
    echo form_submit($loginSubmit);
    echo form_submit($loginForgot);
?>
```

**login_controller**

```
    <?php

    Class Login extends CI_Controller{
       public function __construct() {        
            parent::__construct();
       }

       function index(){
        $data['content'] = 'login_view';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
       }


        function login(){
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $query = $this->login_model->validate();

            if($query){
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('loginEmail'),
                    'loggedin' => true

                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                 redirect('profile/myprofile');
            }
            else{
                echo "not logged in";
            }
        }

    }

    ?>
```

**login_model**

```
 <?php

    Class Login_model extends CI_Model{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function validate(){
            $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('loginEmail'));
            $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('loginPassword')));
             // I also tried with get_where, but same effect. BTW. what is the difference between where() and get_where() and what is better?
            //$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_users', array(('email', $this->input->post('loginEmail'), ('password', $this->input->post('loginPassword')));
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

            if($query->num_rows == 1){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: are you sure you have only one row? "$query->num_rows == 1" What if "$query->num_rows > 0" ?

Comment: I have 2 records in the db and completly different records. Also not possible to register with the same email, so it always has to be 1 or 0

Comment: then I would try to `echo $this->input->post('loginEmail').'-'.md5($this->input->post('loginPassword'));` at your validate function. See if they are the same as in the db.

Comment: It echo's the correct credentials and it is the same like in the db

Comment: What about your **profile** controller? Dont you left some code there that always redirects you back?

Comment: profile controller still doesn't exist. So that shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the function namefrom login to something else (In controller )  as when we create function with same class name it becomes constructor. That is why login function is loading again and again.

Comment: It is always executing ` else{
                echo "not logged in";
            }` even though the credentials are correct

Comment: Yes I know , because login function is executing as constructor . So please change the name of function.if it doesn't work try to debug your code i.e echo $query; die();

Comment: Yeah I changed now the name of the function to: `inloggen()`
But now when I'm logging in, it says basically is saying that the credentials aren't correct

Comment: echo $query isn't returning anything, just empty it seems

Comment: Ok, Now debug model. echo $query; die(); in model. if it doesn't return anything then your login  credentials are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Write else part of model and always close form with form_close() method

```
<?php

        Class Login_model extends CI_Model{

           function validate(){
               $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('loginEmail'));
               $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('loginPassword')));
               // I also tried with get_where, but same effect. BTW. what is the difference between where() and get_where() and what is better?
              //$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_users', array(('email', $this->input->post('loginEmail'), ('password', $this->input->post('loginPassword')));
              $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

              if($query->num_rows == 1){
                return true;
              }
              else{
                return false;
              }    
           }    
        }    
?>
```